# Emperors Gift novel plot hole

Tags: warhammer-40k, space-wolves

I have recently re-read the Novel Emperors Gift. What does bother me is the fact that the Inquisitor is from Fenris.

Knowing the relationship between the Wolves and the Inquisition is there any explanation from the writer how or why this happened?

Wolves are territorial and not subject to Tithes like other worlds in the Imperium. For a black ship to come to Fenris, land and gather children doesn't fit with the continuity.

So I'm interested at how Aaron Dembski-Bowden justified this? Has he made a comment about it at all?

Comment: Also someone from Fenris getting off world would be strange.....as they had viking era technology (the wolves aside)

Comment: The Lexicanum entry for [Annika Jarlsdottyr](http://wh40k-de.lexicanum.com/wiki/Annika_Jarlsdottyr) explains her origins and how she came to be an Inquisitor. It's in German though, so you'll have to use Google translate or find yourself a friendly German.

Comment: @Daft No luck there. Not an explanation of her origin, just an explanation of the book plot.

Comment: I still have not gotten a chance to read that novel yet, but as has been said likely the only way one could get off Fenris is by Fenrisian ship. It is very unlikely a black ship could cull the population without being blown to pieces. To me that says that a Wolf Lord, or likely Grimnar himself, would have allowed her to leave. There probably is no real explanation for how, but if her interactions with the Space Wolves in the book are good that would mean they approve of her current station... I would think it would have been a test or maybe even spy from Grimnar to infiltrate the big I club...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based a little bit on the translation of the Lexicanum entry, I suspect that the answer is that her involvement with the Inquisition pre-dates the Space Wolves and the Inquisition going from "wary" to outright hostile.

That only occurs in 444.M41 with the First War for Armageddon, which is taking place at the same time as the novel itself. Prior to that, it's reasonable that a promising Fenrisian (especially one not eligible for service as a Space Wolf) might be picked up by the Inquisition with authorization of the Space Wolves. Rare, but not impossible.

Comment: That is just it. Knowing the Wolves it seems very, very inplausible that they would allow anybody from landing on Fenris ever. 

Fenris is adeptus grade: NON. It is a space marine homeworld and therfore EXCLUDED from ANY tithes (excluding geeneseed tithe)